# Propel Query and Mysql aggregate functions: cannot use default syntax (<column> = ?, value) inside where filter

Tags: mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4, aggregate-functions, propel

I'm having some troubles creating query conditions in Propel 1.6 using Mysql date functions, such as:

```
$query = PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = ?', $year)->find();
```

The following works:

```
$query = PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = 2011')->find();
```

But in order to handle a $year variable, I then have to write something like:

```
$query = PostQuery::create()->where(sprintf('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = %d', $year))->find();
```

which seems wrong.

I've also tried to specify param type by adding: PDO::PARAM_INT const:

```
$query = PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = ?', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT)->find();
```

This doesn't work.

UPD: There are no errors. Just an empty collection as a result.

Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you having returned?

Comment: There is no error. Just an empty list.

Comment: Is there any chance you could just echo out $year, curious if it's something really silly like your $year variable not being as expected?

Comment: The $year param is correct. I've checked it (I am using XDebug to debug my app).

Answer (score 0):

According to OP

```
// works
PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = 2011')->find();

// doesn't work
PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = ?', $year)->find();
```

This would indicate that PDO is quoting the $year variable so it's actually doing the following when using params

```
PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = \'2011\'')->find();
```

As detailed in this bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639

Do either of these work

```
PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = CONVERT(?,UNSIGNED)', $year,PDO::PARAM_INT)->find();
```

or (this is slightly cleaner)

```
settype($year,'int');
PostQuery::create()->where('YEAR(Post.PublishedAt) = ?', $year,PDO::PARAM_INT)->find();
```

Seems a bit idiotic to have to do it that way but it should convert the numeric string into a MySQL UNSIGNED INT suitable for the WHERE statement.  Either way the above are either having MySQL convert it into a numeric type explicitly, or alternatively trying to ensure that PHP has it explicitly as an INTEGER type before binding it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I suppose, this relates more to Propel Query, than MySQL. But thank you for your try.

Comment: Well either way it does sound like a data type issue, as you said that using the query explicitly functions correctly and so if $year contains 2011, then something funky is happening in the PDO / Propel side of things